# IE7 phantom border-top

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7, border

On this site that i'm working on, http://boldstyle.allthingswebdesign.com there is a gray border-top on the footer ul elements. If you look in FF or chrome, you can see that it creates a subtle effect. If you view it in IE7, the border is way out of place. I cannot figure out why. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` items down there are actually wider than the `ul` so that is an area of concern. I might add a rule like this to override their inherited sizing:

```
#columns .col li { float: none; width: auto; margin: 0; }
```